# Positioning a div relative to SCREEN and a COL div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying do this to long time, but... no luck. The question itself is a little simple.

I need make a div to begin on the left side of screen and ending on the end of a `col-xx-x` div, which in turn is inside a `row` div, which in turn is inside a `container` div.

I've already done it with **jQuery**, but I'm searching for a way to do that using only **HTML** and **CSS**.

I made a image to a better understanding:

[image]

(The red square is the div that i want, but it's obvious)

Note: Notice that on my image I used a `col-md-6` div, but the `col` is indeterminate (col-xx-x), I used 6 only to draw.

Here is a fiddle with the code using **jQuery**:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/b8xcp6j7/

Comment: Can you include `html` and `css` text at Question? _"I made a image to a better understanding:"_ Cannot reproduce issue using image posted at Question.

Comment: Updated, there is a fiddle now.

Comment: Are you trying to position element having text? The rendering at jsfiddle appears different from image at Question?

Comment: What will be as content does not matter, what matter is it position. But if you really wanna know, the content will be an iframe of Google Maps.

Comment: Current `width` of `.box` element is `100%` of its parent element `.col-sm-6`. Are you trying to increase the `width` of `.box` element to be greater than its parent element?

Comment: Yep. If you want you can change everything on the fiddle provided the result is like the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust `.box` element `width` to `200%`, set `position` to `relative`, `left` to `-100%`

```
.box {
  width: 200%;
  border: 4px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  position:relative;
  left:-100%;
}
```

jsfiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/6a0uac4y/2/

Comment: The red box must begin on the left side of screen, **really** on the left side, as if it were stuck each other, and don't surpass it.

Comment: Do you mean `.box` element should not be outside of viewport, but begin at left of viewport?

Comment: Exactly! and ending on the right side of the `.col`

Comment: I want this: [https://fiddle.jshell.net/b8xcp6j7/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/b8xcp6j7/) but only **HTML** and **CSS**

Comment: The closest have been able to get so far `.box-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: calc(-4px + -2vw);
}` https://fiddle.jshell.net/b8xcp6j7/1/